# How to do JSONPath query using a value in the JSON doc

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have following JSON:

```
{
    "person": {
        "id": "5678"
    },
    "result": {
        "accounts": [
            {
                "id": "1234",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "name": "abcd"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "5678",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "name": "efgh"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to find account based on the "id" in the "person" attribute. I tried following:
$..accounts[?@.id == $.person.id]]
and it returns nothing.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

I tried:
$..accounts[?@.id == $.person.id]]

I was expecting following result:

```
{
    "id": "5678",
    "details": [
        {
            "id": "5678",
            "name": "efgh"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `]` on the end of your path.  When I run

```
$..accounts[?@.id == $.person.id]
```

on my playground, https://json-everything.net/json-path, it works as expected and returns:

```json
[
  {
    "Value": {
      "id": "5678",
      "details": [
        {
          "name": "efgh"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Location": "$['result']['accounts'][1]"
  }
]
```